# How to stop CSS within a RichText field from overwriting document

Tags: html, css, xpages

I have a `RichText` field in my document that displays the content of an incoming mail. I noticed whenever there is an HTML email, the CSS in the email overwrites the color of my links and Glyphicon in almost the entire document.

How can I prevent this from happening?

the RichText Field code:

```
<xp:inputRichText value="#{document.Body}" id="body1" htmlFilter="identity"> </xp:inputRichText>
```

Comment: Can you please post some of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

- a "sanitizer" to clean up RichText's HTML from styling or certain styling OR
- own CSS classes for your elements.

Comment: How do i sanitized the RichText element?

Comment: You can use the build-in sanitizer with property `htmlFilter="acf"`/ `htmlFilterIn="acf"` and some configruration in acf-config.xml http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_pref_htmlfilter.html

Comment: We use JTidy in our XPages/Java projects to clean HTML in RichText fields: http://jtidy.sourceforge.net.